# Journey Builder updates All Subscribers List

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

My problem is exactly as described below.

[Journey Builder Sends updates All Subscribers List](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/167258/journey-builder-sends-updates-all-subscribers-list?rq=1)

When I run journey builder using a Sendable DE, it is updating email in All Subscribers list and I don't want to overwrite the email in in All Subscribers list. In the below question, it is mentioned

> just send to the same subscriber again

Not sure how it can be achieved and I don't want to send a second email to the same subscriber. Can you please give some insight on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to update the "All subscribers" list with the desired email address once again.

You can do this by creating an automation and server-side javascript.
Write server-side javascript to retrieve and loop through all the records in your sendable DE  and use the subscriber update method to update the emailaddress back to the original one.

Below is an example using the 
upsert method. This sample code updates the specified values for an existing subscriber or creates a new subscriber if necessary.

```
var newSubscriber = {
"EmailAddress": "test.008@example.com",
"SubscriberKey": "20100730001",
"EmailTypePreference": "Text",
"Attributes":{"First Name": "test.008", "Last Name": "test.008" },
"Lists": {"Status": "Active", "ID": 12345, "Action": "Upsert"}
};

var subObj = Subscriber.Init("SubKey");
var status = subObj.Upsert(newSubscriber);
```

For more details on subscriber related server side javascript methods see [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_subscriberUpsert.htm)