# Prioritize email addresses when there are multiple addresses for a subscriber

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

Our client has several email address fields (3 email address fields) in his Salesforce CRM that he wants to sync with SFMC.
He wants to be able to prioritize which email address field to use to send emails in the following way :

- Use email address #1 by default
- If email address #1 is empty or if email address #1 bounces, use email address #2
- If email address #2 is empty or if email address #1 bounces, use email address #3

Is there anyway to do that with SFMC, Salesforce CRM and MC Connect, or in a general way to prioritize which email address to use (or the conditions to use one or another)?

If it is possible, would the "last successful email address" used for send be updated in All Subscribers and All Contacts?

Answer (score 2):

You will have difficulty sending to more than one email address for a single consumer, as the email address in All Subscribers is leading - regardless what email address you send to. If you send first email to contact 0030X00002EYLjkAYG, with email john@example.com, the email will be sent to john@example.com.

If you, one day later, decide to send to same contact (0030X00002EYLjkAYG) but send to john.doe@example.com, the email will still be sent to john@example.com

You can find more information on how All Subscribers list works in my reply to this question: [Subscriber Key related to Multiple Emails](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/261592/subscriber-key-related-to-multiple-emails/261602#261602)

Answer (score 2):

Also note that you can utilize Salesforce Data Extensions to target and pick the desired email address for a send.  It will not have an automated way of doing so however.

SFDEs are special in that they allow you to have an email address in the DE to target for a send.

This would allow you to send to your subscribers based upon a personal email address, or a business email address.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_salesforce_data_extensions.htm&type=5

Journey Builder also allows you to select an alternate email address for the entry event.  This could be an SF Entry Event or DE entry event.

The email send will change the email address in All Subscribers at time of send.

NOTE: You can only have 1 Email Data Type field in the SFDE for a successful send.

Channel Address Order:

There used to be Channel Address Order where it would go through sources in your desired order to find the contact information:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000339350&type=1&mode=1

and
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_bp_journey_entry_control_best_practices.htm&type=5

I believe this has been deprecated since they allow for the email.

Confirmed:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_january_2017_contact_builder_app.htm&type=5