# How would you update email address in active journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, data-designer

We face a request to update email address that is used for sending in active journey (address could be changed throughout the lifetime of the journey and we need to use up-to-date one).
Additional complexity comes from the fact that we have multiple emails per contact and use SQL for the identification of emails for each journey (based on some business logic). Apparently we need to use "email attribute from Contacts" and create a unique population per journey but that does not seem as viable option.

Any other solutions you might think of?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can utilize the `Use email attribute from Contacts` as a Default Email Address in Journey Settings. However, take into consideration that this checkbox does not imply that you need a separate Attribute Group/Population to use it, as you were mentioning it.

With that, you can have an Automation (SQL to prepare DE and then export and import back to All Subscribers list) or API call, which would update the Email Addresses of the subscribers in the All Subscribers list.
This way, journeys' contacts would always have the correct email address.

Lastly, remember that you can ask SF Support to enable [Email Data Source business rule](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/261592/99298) that would allow you to store and use multiple email addresses for each Subscriber Key, regardless of the email address stored in All Subscribers.

Hopefully, this helps.